# What is this boolean pattern?

Tags: pattern-recognition, derivation-of-formulae

I am trying to come up with an invertable 1 or 2 dimensional transformation that is not unlike the fast fourier transform. Given a prior sequence $A_0 .. A_{n-1}$, we can generate a new sequence of length $ 4 \times n $ as follows: $A_0, A_0, A_1, A_1 .. A_{n-1}, A_{n-1}, A_0, \sim A_0 , A_1, \sim A_1, .. A_{n-1}, \sim A_{n-1}$
Each element is copied twice, then again, but this time each second copy is inverted. (Tilde [`~`] means a bit or sign flip depending on if you define it as a bit or as + or - 1.)

As an example: "1, -1" will become "1, 1; -1, -1; 1, -1; -1, 1"

To make the 2D array, the top row is equivalent to the 1d case, and the whole array has Traspose symmetry ($M_{i,j} = M_{j,i}$) other elements may be determined by taking the product or bitwise xor of the topmost and leftmost elements of the corresponding row/column. Here is a screenshot of a spreadsheet to demonstrate:[image: red and yellow boxes as described, from 1 to 64.]

The idea here is to take the signs of each element in the $4^n$ by $4^n$ Array, and segregate evenly it into $2^n$ by $2^n$ sub arrays, and add each pixel in a $2^n$ square image after multiplying by that matrix. I have empirically determined that taking this "transform" twice does indeed lead to a scaled copy of the original image.

Is there a quick way of generating each kernel sign at $A_k(i, j)$ (where k is the number of iterations to get to a $4^k$ sign matrix) directly, without having to go through the whole duplication process?

Comment: If I understand correctly, each square $A$ is transformed into a square $$\begin{bmatrix} 2A & 2A^c \\ 2A^r & 2A^{rc}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $2A$ stands for $A$ where every cell is duplicated (the size grows twofold, the pattern is the same), $2A^c$ stands for $2A$ where cells are reversed in every other column, $2A^r$ likewise, every other row, and $2A^{rc}$ where cells are reversed in both directions.

Comment: My first reaction would be to consider the binary (or base $4$?) decomposition of $x$ and $y$: you have to find in which of the $4$ subsquares you are, then in which "sub-subsquares", etc. and recover how many reversals there have been to get to the cell $(x,y)$ at step $n$. Still a very rough idea.

Comment: Given a sequence of length $n+1$, you're generating a sequence of length $4n$? Is that right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson given a sequence of $n$, the next sequence is $4n$

Comment: You write, "Given a prior sequence $A_0,\dots,A_n$," mics. That's a sequence of length $n+1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson whoops! my bad, hopefully now it's clear to everyone what I'm trying to explain, it looks like peterwhy has the right answer still, so I'll go ahead and mark that as correct.

Comment: Forget the math. I'm afraid you posted a perfect photo of red and yellow lego bricks. Those 1s are perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will just consider at the top row $A_k(i) := A_k(0,i)$, where $k$ is the number of iterations to get to a $4^k$-sequence. The sequence is from $i=0$ to $i=4^k-1$ inclusive. Each term is either $0$ or $1$.

Define or recall some boolean operations, for $p,q\in\{0,1\}$:

$$\begin{align*}
&\text{XOR:}& p\oplus q &= (p+q)\bmod 2\\
&\text{AND:}& p\cdot q &= pq = p\times q\\
&\text{NOT:}& \neg p &= 1\oplus p
\end{align*}$$

Denote a particular bit of non-negative $i$ by function $b(i,j) \in \{0,1\}$:

$$\begin{align*}
b(i,j)
&= \text{the $\left(2^{j}\right)$s-bit of $i$}\\
&= \left\lfloor \frac{i}{2^{j}}\right\rfloor\bmod 2\\
\text{e.g. }b(10_2, 1) &= 1
\end{align*}$$

Consider the duplication step from $A_{k-1}(\cdot)$ to $A_k(\cdot)$. The sequences have lengths $4^{k-1}$ and $4^k$ respectively. For the entry $A_k(i)$:

- If $0\le i < 4^k/2 = 2^{2k-1}$, then $A_k(i)$ copies $A_{k-1}\left(\lfloor i/2\rfloor\right)$;

  - $0\le i < 2^{2k-1}$: the most-significant $\left(2^{2k-1}\right)$s-bit is $0$, i.e. $b(i,2k-1) = 0$;
- If $i$ is even, then $A_k(i)$ copies $A_{k-1}\left(\lfloor i/2\rfloor\bmod 4^{k-1}\right)$;

  - $i$ is even: the least-significant $1$s-bit is $0$, i.e. $b(i,0) = 0$;
  - $\lfloor i/2\rfloor\bmod 4^{k-1}$: the "middle" bits of $i$, discarding the $1$s-bit (right-shift by $1$) and the $\left(2^{2k-1}\right)$s-bit.
- Otherwise if both $2^{2k-1}\le i < 4^k$ AND $i$ is odd, then $A_k(i)$ is $\neg A_{k-1}\left(\lfloor i/2\rfloor\bmod 4^{k-1}\right)$.

Recursively, that means to consider the $\left(2^{2k-1}\right)$s-bit AND the $1$s bit, to conditionally flip $A_{k-1}\left(\lfloor i/2\rfloor\bmod 4^{k-1}\right)$.

Represent $i$ in binary, then the following calculation may be easy to understand and calculate.

$$\begin{align*}
A_k(i)
&= \left[\left(2^{2k-1}\text{s-bit}\right) \cdot \left(1\text{s-bit}\right)\right] \oplus \left[A_{k-1}\left(\text{"middle" bits of }i\right)\right]\\
&= \left[b\left(i,2k-1\right)\cdot b\left(i,0\right)\right] \oplus \left[A_{k-1}\left(\text{"middle" bits of }i\right)\right]\\
&= \vdots\\
&= \left[b\left(i, 2k-1\right)\cdot b\left(i,0\right)\right] \oplus \cdots \oplus \left[b\left(i, k\right)\cdot b\left(i, k-1\right)\right] \oplus \left[A_{0}\left(0\right)\right]\\
&= \left[b\left(i, 2k-1\right)\cdot b\left(i,0\right)\right] \oplus \cdots \oplus \left[b\left(i, k\right)\cdot b\left(i, k-1\right)\right]\\
&= \bigoplus_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[b\left(i, 2k-1-j\right)\cdot b\left(i, j\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

In terms of mod 2 and floored division,

$$\begin{align*}
A_k(i)
&= \left[\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2^{2k-1-j}}\right\rfloor \bmod 2\right)\cdot\left(\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2^{j}}\right\rfloor\bmod 2\right)\right] \bmod 2\\
&= \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left\lfloor \frac{i}{2^{2k-1-j}}\right\rfloor \cdot\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2^{j}}\right\rfloor\right) \bmod 2\\
\end{align*}$$

---

For example, in the $4^2\times 4^2$ square ($k=2$), the term with index $13$ (counting from $0$) is

$$\begin{align*}
A_2(0,13)
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{13}{2^{2\cdot2-1}}\right\rfloor \cdot\left\lfloor \frac{13}{2^{0}}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{13}{2^{2\cdot2-2}}\right\rfloor \cdot\left\lfloor \frac{13}{2^{1}}\right\rfloor\right)\bmod 2\\
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{13}{8}\right\rfloor \cdot\left\lfloor \frac{13}{1}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{13}{4}\right\rfloor \cdot\left\lfloor \frac{13}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\bmod 2\\
&= \left(1 \cdot 13 + 3 \cdot 6\right)\bmod 2\\
&= 1\\
& \text{(represented as $(-1)^{A_2(0,13)} = -1$ in the image)}
\end{align*}$$